# In vue.js, is it possible to read the headers of the request?

Tags: vue.js, request, amazon-cloudfront, request-headers

Cloudfront is passing headers to our vue page, and we would like to read them. Is this possible? Haven't found anything on the net so far. Thanks!

Comment: No. You cannot read request headers directly from JS - you'd need some sort of server-side script to achieve this.

Comment: Note that you may need to clarify whether you are looking for *request* headers or *response* headers.  You said "request" but it sounds as if you are talking about the response.

Comment: The client (browser) is hitting my vue (nuxt) app. I want to get the request headers sent by the client.

Comment: Please don't add completely irrelevant tags like [tag:brainfuck] to your questions.